# When creating Facebook ads through API, it prompts “enroll_status was not provided”

Tags: facebook, ads

The question like https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1369234493639891/

I added the parameter standard_enhancements > enroll_status > OPT_OUT
but I still failed to create an ad. Part of the request parameters are as follows:

```
{
  "object_story_spec": {
    "page_id": "xxxxx",
    "video_data": {
      "call_to_action": {
        "type": "INSTALL_APP",
        "value": {
          "link": ""
        }
      },
      "image_hash": "{result=videoThumbnailRequestxxxxxxxxxxxxx:$.images.*.hash}",
      "title": "",
      "video_id": "{result=videoRequestxxxxxxxxxxxxx:$.id}"
    }
  },
  "title": "test",
  "body": "test",
  "degrees_of_freedom_spec": {
    "creative_features_spec": {
      "standard_enhancements": {
        "enroll_status": "OPT_OUT"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Invalid parameter",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 3858082,
      "is_transient": false,
      "error_user_title": "Creative Must Provide enroll_status for Standard Enhancements",
      "error_user_msg": "This creative is eligible for Standard Enhancements, but enroll_status was not provided. Please choose whether you want to turn on standard enhancements or not. Learn more here: https://fburl.com/hyth50xo",
      "fbtrace_id": "AZGGOCEVV3jyJ09T0SV0yXO"
    }
  },
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Request aborted. This could happen if a dependent request failed or the entire request timed out.",
      "type": "FacebookApiException",
      "code": 960,
      "fbtrace_id": "A1m-jT3shoLxOqMFdVxhxdU"
    }
  }
]
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/advantage-catalog-ads/standard-enhancements

Comment: Are you supposed to send all this as one single JSON structure? The example in the manual uses cURL option `-F`, so they are sending individual POST parameters named `name`, `object_story_spec` and `degrees_of_freedom_spec` there.

Comment: Hi there and congrats on your first question in stack overflow!

Please avoid posing stackoverflow questions by linking to a question on an external website for the following reasons:
- folks that would like to help you now need to navigate to another page - it is a more cumbersome experience for them
- the link might not longer work in the future, and so anyone revisiting this stack overflow question will no longer be able to get the full details 

The better we form our questions and answers on stackoverflow, the more useful stackoverflow will be for all of us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this issue has been fixed by the Meta. Please check if you encounter the same problem. You can verify by examining the sample request body below, it is working fine for me.

```
{
    'name': 'test - Creative',
    'object_story_spec': {
        'page_id': '<page_id>',
        'link_data': {
            'description': '',
            'image_hash': '<image_hash>',
            'link': '<link>',
            'message': 'message',
            'name': 'headline',
            'call_to_action': {
                'type': 'LEARN_MORE',
                'value': {
                    'link': '<link>',
                    'link_caption': ''
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'degrees_of_freedom_spec': {
        'creative_features_spec': {
            'standard_enhancements': {
                'enroll_status': 'OPT_OUT'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error using the Ad object create_copy() functionality. How may I pass the enroll_status as OPT OUT via the code using create_copy?

Additionally, if you can tell me on the Business Manager how do I set it to opt out so we can then just copy this ad into other adset via code will also be helpful

Thanks